# Field Extension with primitive roots of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I want to prove that |$\mathbb{Q}(\omega):\mathbb{Q}(t)|=2$ with $\omega$ a primitive nth root of unity and $t=\omega +\omega ^{-1}$
So for any element $q \in \mathbb{Q}(\omega)$, I need to find a basis $f_1,f_2$ such that $q=af_1 + bf_2$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}(t)$ and then prove it is a basis. Is this correct? and I can't find a suitable basis so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think a slicker method would be via tower law, do you know it?

Comment: You do know that $\omega$ is a root of the polynomial $x^2-tx+1=(x-\omega)(x-\omega^{-1})$, don't you?

Comment: @mdave16  Yes I do, what would be the intermediary field?

Comment: Do you know the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory?  $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ is the fixed field of complex conjugation $\tau$.  $\tau$ generates a subgroup of order $2$, so its corresponding fixed field has index $2$.

Comment: @BradleyHill, I was thinking the intermediate group would be $\mathbb{Q}(t)$, as JykriLahtonen mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the polynomial $$p(x)=x^2-tx+1=(x-\omega)(x-\omega^{-1}) \in \mathbb{Q}(t)[x]$$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ (why?) and $x=\omega$ is one of it's roots, hence it's the minimal polynomial of $\omega$ over $\mathbb{Q}(t)$, therefore $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega):\mathbb{Q}(t)]=\partial(p)=2$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm quite new to this topic so is there a method to tell if a polynomial is irreducible?

Comment: Notice that the factorization of $p(x)$ is $(x-\omega)(x-\omega^{-1})$, and the factorization is unique. Hence the factors aren’t of the form $$a+bt=a+b(\omega+\omega^{-1}),$$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!!

Comment: You’re welcome :)